# How to display unicode control characters in visual studio text visualizer?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unicode

I get some text string from service, which contains Unicode control characters
(i.e `\u202B` or `\u202A` and others for Arabic language support).

But while debugging I can't see them in default text visualizer. So I need to enable display for such characters to determine which of them my text consists of. There is checkbox in text visualizer "show all characters", but it doesn't work as I expect.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use the string's ToCharArray() method in the watch expression to see the code points.  Right-click + Hexadecimal Display is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Those are codes for explicit RLE and LRE order, ie if in RLE something should be displayed in LRE order.

http://unicode.org/reports/tr9/#Directional_Formatting_Codes